# showing autocomplete elements with rails4-autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I wrote a custom autocomplete function that does a search on a join table

I verified that the search does indeed work,but the problem is that jquery is not rendering the results properly

this is my custom autocomplete method

```
def autocomplete_property_address
    properties = Property.address_theme_joint_table(current_user.company.theme_name,"%#{params[:term]}%")
    #render properties
    render :json => properties.map{ |property|{:id => property.id, :address => property.address}}
end
```

and here is the view

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "search-query", placeholder: "Address search", type: "search", data: {autocomplete: autocomplete_property_address_properties_path}, :id_element => '', :update_elements => {} %>
```

the result looks like this:
[image]

the results are not being rendered properly, but it i know its there!

Answer (score 0):

Your 'data-autocomplete' attribute is not set properly. Try this instead:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "search-query", :placeholder => "Address search", :type => "search", "data-autocomplete" => autocomplete_property_address_properties_path, :id_element => '', :update_elements => {} %>
```

Comment: well, there is another part of the question: what HTML did you really want out of that 'text_field_tag'?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by what HTML, but I was using the rails4-autocomplete gem originally and had to write my own own method instead because the gem doesn't support searches on a join table apparently. I'm thinking the gem has something to do with rendering the results